# get form state values of forms which added via ajax

Tags: forms, ajax

the forms were added via ajax,but I just don't know how to get $values= $form_state['values']['field_name']; ,the result return nothing.Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

/**
 * hook_menu()
 */

function addstudent_menu(){
    $items= array();
    $items['user/%/add-students'] = array(
        'title'=>t('添加學生賬戶'),
        'page callback' =>'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array(addstudent_form),
        'access arguments' => array('create new users'),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,


    );

    return $items;

}


function addstudent_form($form,&$form_state){

    $dropdown_source = taxonomy_get_tree(3);
    if(!empty($dropdown_source)){
        $options = array('0'=> '--none--');

        foreach($dropdown_source as $item){ //we get all class term here
            $key = $item->tid;
            $value =$item->name;
            $options[$key] = $value;
        }
    }else {
        drupal_set_message(t('你还没有创建任何班级'),'error');
    }


    $form['addstudent_wrapper'] = array(
        '#title' => t('添加學生賬戶'),
        '#type' =>'fieldset',
        '#prefix'=>'<div id="fields_wrapper">',
        '#suffix'=> '</div>',

    );


    $form['addstudent_wrapper']['fields_head']['select_class'] = array(
        '#title'=> t('班级'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options'=>$options
    );

    $form['addstudent_wrapper']['fields_head']['student_qty'] = array(
        '#title' => t('人數'),
        '#type'=> 'textfield',
        '#size'=> 10,

    );




    $form['addstudent_wrapper']['fields_head']['add'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value'=> '確認',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'addstudent_get_callback',
            'wrapper' =>'fields_wrapper',

        ),
    );






    $form['addstudent_wrapper']['fields_wrapper']=array(
        '#tree' => TRUE,
    );





    return $form;

}




function addstudent_get_callback($form,&$form_state){
    $form_state['rebulid'] = TRUE;
    $i = $form_state['values']['student_qty'];
    return $form['addstudent_wrapper']['fields_wrapper'] = _addstudent_fields($i);

}




function  _addstudent_fields($i){
    for($a=0;$a<$i;$a++){

        $form[$a]['field_number'] = array(
            '#title' => '學號',
            '#markup'=>$a+1,
            '#tree' =>TRUE,
            '#type'=>'markup'

        );

        $form[$a]['field_name'] = array(
            '#title' => '姓名',
            '#type'=> 'textfield',
            '#tree' => TRUE,
            '#parents' => array('field_name', $i, 'field_name'),
            '#size'=> 10,
            '#default_value'=>''
        );
    }

    $form['addstudent_wrapper']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Confirm',
        '#submit' => array('addstudent_form_submit'),
    );


    return $form;
}

function addstudent_form_submit($form,&$form_state){

    $values= $form_state['values']['field_name'];
    $a = array_values($values);
    foreach($a AS $b){
        foreach($b as $c){
            $r[] = $c;
        }
    }

    dsm($values);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$values= $form_state['values'];`

and then dsm the values. You will get all field values of the form.

I think you should get the form values of ajax in `$form_state['values']['addstudent_wrapper']['fields_wrapper'][0]['field_name']` and so on.

Comment: it must work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below an example taken from the drupal [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module; Hope it helps

```
function ajax_example_submit_driven_ajax($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['box'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="box">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#markup' => '<h1>Initial markup for box</h1>',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_submit_driven_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'box',
    ),
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Select the 'box' element, change the markup in it, and return it as a
 * renderable array.
 *
 * @return renderable array (the box element)
 */
function ajax_example_submit_driven_callback($form, $form_state) {
  // In most cases, it is recomended that you put this logic in form generation
  // rather than the callback. Submit driven forms are an exception, because
  // you may not want to return the form at all.
  $element = $form['box'];
  $element['#markup'] = "Clicked submit ({$form_state['values']['op']}): " . date('c');
  return $element;
```